Deploying Flask app to uwsgi with background process with python multiprocessing
I have a flask app that streams footage from a camera with low framerate (with pypylon). In order to speed up the footage I created a process that continuously retrieve a frame from the camera because each grab takes a while. It works completely fine with the python server but it does not work in uwsgi
Camera.py
class Camera:
    ...
    current_frame=None

def capture():
    while Camera.on:
      current_frame = capture_frame_from_camera()

def get_processed_frame():
    return Camera.current_frame


main.py
from multiprocess import Process
from Camera import get_processed_frame, capture
def generate_frames():
    while True:
        frame = get_processed_frame()
        if frame is not None:
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n') 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

camera_process = Process(target=capture)
camera_process.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')


The above is some code that was written (not all of it). If I run python main.py then it works perfectly ok. But for some reasons running uwsgi --http :8000 -w main:app will completely block camera process from continuously running. I am not sure if I want to use celery because I'm not sure how to keep it as performant as it is since it uses a message queue. If there is a way to use celery and keep the frame rate that would be amazing, but if there is a way to run the app on uwsgi as is that would be amazing
